# how does qemu-img merge the QCOW2 delta images

Tags: openstack, qemu, kvm

Hello everyone，I am a newcomer.
I am learning OpenStack and kvm, but now I met a difficult problem:

I have a qcow2 image **A**,
a qcow2 delta image **B** whose backing file is **A**,
and a qcow2 image **C** whose backing file is **B**.

Now I want to merge **B** and **C** into a new qcow2 image **D** whose backing file is **A**.

I have tried to use `qemu-img` to solve it, but still didn't get positive solutions.
I hope you can help me, really appreciate.

Comment: Please read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the vm in question currently running use a virsh blockpull.

```
virsh blockpull --domain vmname --path /var/lib/libvirt/images/c.qcow2
```

this assumes vmname is the vm using c.qcow2 which is backed by b.qcow2 which is backed by a.qcow2.
If you'd like a file other than c.qcow2 to be the final new complete backless file, then use the vm and create a d.qcow2 first and name it in the virsh command. This will leave a,b,c intact and pull a+b+c into d.

And yes, the domain is to be up and running while you do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
cp C D
qemu-img rebase -b A D
```

This creates a copy of `C` called `D` and then rebases `D` on `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does work! [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68796338/qemu-img-commit-complete-backing-chain-or-delete-empty-middle-overlay/68808111#68808111)

**Situation**:

```
A <- B <- C
```

**Task**:

```
A <- D(B2&C2)
```

**Solution**:

```
A <- D <- B <- C
```

What you need to do, is:

1. Create a new - and therefore empty - snapshot for A.
2. Make copies of B and C as B2 and C2.
3. Rebase B2 to D.
4. Rebase C2 to B2.
5. Commit C2 to B2 and delete C2.
6. Commit B2 to D and delete B2.

What remains is D, containing B and C, with A as base. Done. This is possible because inserting an EMPTY snapshot into an existing chain of snapshots is possible.