# qemu-img convert a overlay qcow2 image into a entire image

Tags: qemu

I have a base image file "base.qcow2" and a delta qcow2 image file "delta.qcow2" whose backing file is "base.qcow2".

Now I use qemu-img to convert "delta.qcow2" and will get a new image file "new.qcow2" which is entire and equivalent to combination of "base.qcow2" and "delta.qcow2".

In fact, i just want to convert the delta qcow2 image file and get a new delta overlay qcow2 image file. So the "new.qcow2" is not what i want. Is there any way to convert a overlay qcow2 image itself?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is discussed here:
[Same Question to qemu Community](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1662050)

But I was searching for following: I've a base and several snapshots.

**I want to compress / merge / put together / zip (the keyword you are looking for is "*merge*") them into one single Image.**

And Google always returned to this question. So this is a hint for all who went the same way ;).

```
qemu-img rebase -F $YourSourceFormat -b '' -f $YourTargetFormat delta.qcow2
$-> e.g qcow2
```

This function is hidden the rebase command. Rebase for normal compares two images and adding the changes from on to an other. But what happens if you only enter one archive, which is the head of a whole backing chain. Haha, you will receive a totally brand new stand alone image of it. Isn't it great?

Btw. if you are going to use the head snapshot, you might want to backup it in before.

Useful links:

- [This links was helpful in solving the problem](https://docs-old.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Virtualization_Administration_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Tips_and_tricks-Using_qemu_img.html)
- [This is the Version how you do it with virsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37323620/how-does-qemu-img-merge-the-qcow2-delta-images)
- [More hardcore virsh solution](https://kashyapc.fedorapeople.org/virt/lc-2012/snapshots-handout.html)